# in Swift, how to fetch and convert Firestore timestamp field

Tags: ios, swift, date, timestamp

I'm setting up my first Firestore database and I have several date fields stored as timestamps.  In my swift struct, the corresponding properties are declared as Date.  First question - is that the correct way to do it?  if so, how do I fetch those timestamp values?  I've been trying to find the solution but it does not seem to be obvious solution.

```
struct HealthLog1: Codable {
   var comment: String?
   var entryDate: Date?
   var familyMemberID: String?
   var logID: String?
   var user_ID: String?
 }



 db.collection("healthLogs").whereField("familyMemberID", isEqualTo: person.familyMemberID!).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        
        if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
            
            for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                
                let log = HealthLog1(
                    comment: doc["comment"] as? String,
                    entryDate: doc["entryDate"] as? Date,
                    familyMemberID: doc["familyMemberID"] as? String,
                    logID: doc["logID"] as? String,
                    user_ID: doc["user_ID"] as? String)
   
                healthLogs.append(log)

            }
            
            self.delegateHLP?.receiveLogs(healthLogs: healthLogs)
        }
        else {
            print ("there is some error with the get documents")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare date as a Timestamp.

Your model

```
class HealthLog1: Codable {
    var comment: String?
    var entryDate: Timestamp? //<-- Declare Timestamp
    var familyMemberID: String?
    var logID: String?
    var user_ID: String?
}
```

Init

```
let log = HealthLog1(
    comment: doc["comment"] as? String,
    entryDate: doc["entryDate"] as? Timestamp,
    familyMemberID: doc["familyMemberID"] as? String,
    logID: doc["logID"] as? String,
    user_ID: doc["user_ID"] as? String)
```

If you need date from Timestamp value then use `dateValue()`:

```
let entryDate = log.entryDate.dateValue()
```